# How do I access a Terms DueDays, DiscountDays using IPP v3

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am using the .NET v3 Developer Kit. 
How do I access a Terms DueDays, DiscountDays using IPP v3

In v2 I would use the term object's Items array property. But is gone in v3.

Any advise on how to get this?

Answer (score 1):

```
        Term term = new Term();
        term.Name = "Name";
        term.Active = true;
        term.ActiveSpecified = true;
        term.Type = "STANDARD";
        term.DiscountPercent = new Decimal(50.00);
        term.DiscountPercentSpecified = true;
        term.AnyIntuitObjects = new Object[] { 10 };
        term.ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType[] { ItemsChoiceType.DueDays };
```

Answer (score -1):

What happened to the terms.Items array that contains the values to set?  There is no obvious way to set the values in v3.

Comment: V3 services request/response format is different than v2. So, the same objects/classes might not be available in v3